# 100% height layout not showing properly

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm struggling with this a little while.

I wish to create a layout which looks as follows:

```
+-------------+
|   Header    |
+-------------+
| box1 | box2 |
+-------------+
```

When the header supposed to be 60% percent of the window height, and the 2 boxes height is exactly the rest 40% of the page.

Now, when zooming in or changing resolution, the boxes should both 100% width and have enough height for their contents.

I currently use **bootsrap**, and the following:

```
#header {
    margin  :   0 !important;
    overflow:   hidden;
    height  :   60vh;
    width   :   100%;
}

.jumbotron{
    margin  :   0px !important;
    padding :   0px !important;
}
#footer{
    width   :   100%;
    margin  :   0   !important;
    padding :   0 !important;
    border:1px solid red;
    min-height  :   40%;
    max-height:100%;

}

#main-content{
    height  :100%;
}
html,body{
    height  :   100%;
}

#boxes-wrap{
    width   :   100% !important;
    margin  :   0   !important;
    border  :   1px solid blue;
    height  :   100%;
}
.box{
    height  :   100%;
    text-align  :   center;
    padding     :   20px;
}
```

Now what happens is that the boxes dont fill all the space, and there's this ugly spacing between the bottom of the page and the boxes (footer).

But when I use this:

```
#footer{
    width   :   100%;
    margin  :   0   !important;
    padding :   0 !important;
    border:1px solid red;
    min-height  :   40vh;
    max-height:100%;

}
```

The initial state looks good, but when changing the resolution some of the contents of the boxes go out of box bounding.

How can I fix this? How can I make this layout fill all the page and yet make it responsive?

jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/yxef2huw/1/

Comment: Share your HTML and CSS as snippet using this http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: fiddled @hemnathmouli

Comment: @superuser123 where is the link ?

Comment: Haaaave you met flexbox? https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Answer (score 0):

[Check this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yxef2huw/3/)

I have changed : these classes

```
.jumbotron{
        margin  :   0px !important;
        padding :   0px !important;
      height:60%
    }

#footer{
    width   :   100%;
    margin  :   0   !important;
    padding :   0 !important;
    border:1px solid red;
    height  :   40%;
    max-height:100%;
  max-width:100%;

}
.box:first-child{
    background  :   red;
  float:left;
  width:50%
}

.box:last-child{
    background  :   blue;
  float:left;
  width:50%
}
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: can u provide the content you are loading ? so that i can edit fiddle code accordingly